# Send Location Data to OpenGTS from Android

Tags: android, location, opengts

We would like to create an android app, that sends the location of the phone every "x" Minutes to an OpenGTS Server.

Therefore we already installed the OpenGTS Server an testet the functionality with a free app, that can be found in the play store.

For the next step, we would like to integrate this functionality into our company app. Unfortunately we can't find any code that can help us developing this.

There are some requirements for our app:

- The user should not be able to disable GPS
- The location of our device should be send every x Minutes
- If there is no available internet connection, the locations should be saved locally and afterwards send to the OpenGTS Server.

Is there any SDK or OpenSource Project where we can find code, that could help us with our project?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Type opengps server in your search machine and you will discover that it is open source. No you cannot prevent the user to switch gps on/off. In fact you will always need the user to switch it on/off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Traccar Client app](https://www.traccar.org/client/). Source code for Android version can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-android).

I'm not sure if OpenGTS supports it by default, but you can always [integrate Traccar GPS tracking server with OpenGTS](https://www.traccar.org/opengts/).

Comment: Is there a good tutorial how to install Traccar? The documentation of Traccar is a little bit poor

Comment: To install you just need to download the installer and run it.